# MySQL and node.js JOIN statement with user input

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have two tables in MySQL workbench which are `event` and `location`. I'm trying to join both tables and extract the information from them based on user input. The problem is that I'm getting a MySQL syntax error and I don't know how to solve it.

```
app.get("/coordinates/:id", (req,res) =>{
    console.log(req.params.id);
    let sql = `SELECT Latitude, Longitude FROM event`
     + ` JOIN location ON location.EventID = event.Id`;
      db.query(sql, (err,result) =>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    console.log(result)
    res.status(200).json({
        data: result
     })
   })
})
```

The following code works fine but I want instead of `event.Id` I want  to substitute it with `event.${req.params.id}`, but I'm getting this error

`ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':4' at line 1` and in all honesty I'm kinda lost as to what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how you want to join on user selection can you give a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because generated statement is wrong syntactically  let say that user input is `12` then the statement will be

```
SELECT Latitude, Longitude FROM event JOIN location ON location.EventID = event.12
```

so if you want to join on for example 12 so statement should be

```
SELECT Latitude, Longitude FROM event JOIN location ON location.EventID = 12
```

so it should be  `${req.params.id}`  instead of `event.${req.params.id}`

but I think this statement will be wrong semantically may be you should filter after joining as following

```
SELECT Latitude, Longitude FROM event JOIN location ON location.EventID = event.id where event.id = ${req.params.id}
```

or according to what do you want to get

Comment: Hey Ahmed, thanks for the feedback. The filtering after joining the tables worked as expected. Turns out that I had one more mistake when trying to call this route. Now everything works. Cheers!

Comment: great but take care of SQL injection this example may lead to SQL injection issue you need to handle it

Comment: check this link https://www.veracode.com/blog/secure-development/how-prevent-sql-injection-nodejs